# how to Find/Replace multiple lines in Notepad++ within a FOLDER?

Tags: plugins, notepad++

is there any plugins for notepad++ existed to replace multiple lines within a FOLDER? (not a single file).

Answer (score 4):

If you mean you need to replace texts in multiple files inside a folder, then you may use **Replace in Files**.

Press <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> > **Find in Files** tab -> set the options as needed and click **Replace in Files** button.

If you check *In all subfolders*, all files in the subfolders that match the selected mask will be processed recursively.

[image]